# What should you call your siblings who are each others' twins?

Tags: phrases

If you had a twin of the opposite sex, you would say "X is my twin [brother/sister]". It's understood that you are one of the two twins.

But if you had two siblings who were twins of each other, and you are not one of the twins, how would you refer to them in a way that emphasizes they have a twin, and they are your sibling, but without implying you are one of the twins?

Comment: Interesting question. Most families would refer to them as "the twins"; as their brother, you could say "my brothers, the twins".

Comment: I'm not sure there's a single word for "my brother, who is one of a pair of twins, the other one of which is not me". Are you implying there is such a word in your own language?

Comment: "This is my brother Tim, my other brother Tom's twin."

Comment: Some languages have very precise terminology for all sorts of familial relations. English isn't one of them.

Comment: *My siblings who are twins.* *My sisters who are twins.* *My brother and sister who are twins.* Just don't add a comma, as that suggests that these are your *only* siblings.

Comment: "This is one of my twin brothers, Tim, ...".

Comment: "This is my brother Tim, the twin" or "This is my brother Tim, one of the twins". Assumes that the listener already has some idea that there might be twins.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest "my brother/sister X, who's a twin". It's a bit awkward, admittedly; but I think the reason it's a bit awkward is that X's twin-ness is not usually relevant, so it's not clear why you're bringing it up. (In a context where the twin-ness really *is* relevant — like, if the conversation is about twins in some way — then it becomes completely non-awkward IMHO.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to both twins simultaneously, you could say "my twin brothers/sisters/siblings". Though that could lead people to believe that you're incorrectly referring to your triplet siblings.